Package conflicts in Julia (Multilayered network analysis)
I'm new to Julia from python and the initial environment are quiet different.
Recently, I face conflict with julia packages in using Multilayer Graphs.
When I add Pkg.add("MultilayerGraphs"), it gets me as below.
Please give me any comment on that.

julia> import Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("MultilayerGraphs")
    Updating registry at `C:\Users\.julia\registries\General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CUDA [052768ef]:
 CUDA [052768ef] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-5.4.2 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions: 0.1.0-5.4.2
 ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [2.3.0, 2.5.0-5.4.2] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [2.3.0, 2.5.0-5.4.2]
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with GPUCompiler [61eb1bfa] to versions: 5.0.0-5.4.2 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 5.0.0-5.4.2
 │ └─GPUCompiler [61eb1bfa] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.26.5 or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions: 0.1.0-0.26.5
 │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with CUDA [052768ef] to versions: [0.3.0-0.7.3, 0.8.1-0.10.0, 0.11.1-0.12.9, 0.13.3-0.21.4, 0.24.0-0.26.5]
 │   │ └─CUDA [052768ef] log: see above
 │   └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 0.22.0-0.26.5 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.24.0-0.26.5
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with TensorOperations [6aa20fa7] to versions: 1.0.0-3.13.1 — no versions left
   └─TensorOperations [6aa20fa7] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.6.1-4.1.1 or uninstalled
     └─restricted by compatibility requirements with MultilayerGraphs [af984530] to versions: 3.2.0-3.2.5
       └─MultilayerGraphs [af984530] log:
         ├─possible versions are: 0.1.1-1.1.4 or uninstalled
         └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions: 0.1.1-1.1.4

I did several try to version specification in pkg install. but it didnt work

I am not in front a pc now, but try by installing that package in a new environment that you use only for this work, with only the packages you need. Environments in Julia are "cheap", so you usualy start a script with something like Pkg.activate(@__DIR__) to create/activate an environment specific to the directory where the script is located...

The pkg activation is working but somehow error message is still showing. Can somebody recommend the right version
